# pasar una lista de parametros en SQL a C# MVC

Tags: c#, sql

necesito hacer un filtro para un Ecomerce  por lo que necesito pasar una tabla caracteristicas con el numero de unidades que tiene de esa caracteristica (por ejemplo baños que tiene id 4 y podria tener 5 unidades ) para eso hice un tipo en SQL

```
CREATe TYPE [dbo].[caracteristicas] AS TABLE(
    [IdCaractProp] [int] NULL,
    Seleccionado int null
)
GO
```

hice este procedimiento almacenado

```
-- Construir la consulta dinámica para la condición de superficie
ALTEr procedure sp_pruebaFiltros (
    @caracteristicas [caracteristicas] READONLY 
)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm 
        WHERE IdCaractProp IN (SELECT IdCaractProp FROM  @caracteristicas)
        AND Seleccionado IN (SELECT Seleccionado from @caracteristicas)
END
```

Creé una tabla a modo de ejemplo en el controlador

```
public ActionResult PruebaFiltros()
    {
        var PropiedadesEcomerce = new ListaPropiedadesEcomerce();

        // Crear una lista de objetos caracteristicas
        List<caracteristicas> caracteristicasList = new List<caracteristicas>
        {
            new caracteristicas { IdCaractProp = 14, Seleccionado = 0 },
            new caracteristicas { IdCaractProp = 15, Seleccionado = 0 },
            new caracteristicas { IdCaractProp = 16, Seleccionado = 0 }
        };

        var Filtros = _PropiedadesData.FiltrosEcomerce(caracteristicasList);


        return View(PropiedadesEcomerce);
    }
```

y dicha tabla se la pase en el center esperando que pasara los parametros los leyera de la tabla y me regresara los ID de la propiedad con esas caracteristicas

```
public ListaPropiedadesEcomerce FiltrosEcomerce(List<caracteristicas> caracteristicasList)
    {
        var oListaPropiedad = new ListaPropiedadesEcomerce();


        // Crear una tabla DataTable y mapear los datos de la lista de caracteristicas
        DataTable caracteristicasTable = new DataTable();
        caracteristicasTable.Columns.Add("IdCaractProp", typeof(int));
        caracteristicasTable.Columns.Add("Seleccionado", typeof(int));

        foreach (var caracteristica in caracteristicasList)
        {
            caracteristicasTable.Rows.Add(caracteristica.IdCaractProp, caracteristica.Seleccionado);
        }

        var cn = new Conexion();
         
        using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(cn.getConnSQL()))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_pruebaFiltros", conexion);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Configurar el parámetro de tabla tipo
            SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("caracteristicas", caracteristicasTable);
            parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            parameter.TypeName = "dbo.caracteristicas";

            // Abrir la conexión y ejecutar el comando
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Procesar los resultados
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                int seleccionado = reader.GetInt32(1);

                // Crear una instancia de la clase propiedad y asignar los valores
                propiedad prop = new propiedad
                {
                    PropiedadID = id
                };

                // Agregar la propiedad a la lista PropiedadIds
                oListaPropiedad.PropiedadIds.Add(prop);
            }

        }


        return oListaPropiedad;

    }
```

pero en esta linea:

```
             SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

me da este error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 2 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 1 column(s).'

Comment: La llamada al sqlParameter, debería de ser: `SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caracteristicas", caracteristicasTable);`

Comment: Por otro lado, porque hacer en el procedimiento dos `IN`, cuando podrías hacer directamente un join. `SELECT * FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm E JOIN @caracteristicas t on E.IdCaractProp = t.IdCaractProp And E.Seleccionado = t.Seleccionado`

Answer (score 0):

encontre el error , por alguna razon anteriormente tenia caracteristicas de la siguiente forma

> CREATe TYPE [dbo].[caracteristicas] AS TABLE(
> [IdCaractProp] [int] NULL,
> ) GO

luego elimine el tipo, lo volvi a hacer y funciono